# .NET Core Reference Source

Tags: c#, .net-core, code-documentation

I was searching for the source code of .NET Core because I wanted to look at how the core classes are implemented. For example, I wanted to see how the `string` class is written.
Can someone please point me to the source code of .NET Core?

There exists a great online browsing tool for .NET Framework at
[.NET Reference Resource](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs).
Does something similar exist for .NET Core?

PS: I tried looking on GitHub but could not find it.

[This GitHub Link](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/releases/tag/v3.1.408) allows to download SDK source code but it has missing classes like String.cs

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The equivalent of the .NET Framework Referece Source website for Core is [.NET Source Browser](https://source.dot.net).

Where you can find [String](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/String.cs,8281103e6f23cb5c).

MIT Licensed.

Comment: The .NET Source Browser is great resource, but its for the NEXT version of .NET 7.  Is there an option or other resource for *current*  version ( .NET 6 as for today ) ?

Answer (score 3):

Look in the [dotnet/runtime](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime) repo on GitHub:

You'll find the implementation of the `String` class there:
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/String.cs